# Small doubt concerning treatment of filters in v. Dalen's L&S

Tags: logic, filters

This is a rather miniscule —and most likely borne of misunderstanding— doubt concerning the treatment and definition of "filters" (in particular their characterization as "proper") in section 4.5 ("Ultraproducts") of professor v. Dalen's *Logic and Structure*, but I have nonetheless decided on asking here so as to definitively clear any doubts thereof.

In the aforementioned section, Dalen defines a *filter* as:

**Definition 4.5.1** Let $I$ be a non-empty set. $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{P}(I)$ is a *filter* if

(i) $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{F} \implies \mathcal{A} \cap \mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{F}$

(ii) $\mathcal{A} \in \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{B} \implies \mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{F}$

(iii) $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{F}$ (the filter is *proper*)

We assume $\mathcal{F} \neq \emptyset$ [$\dots$]

Now, right off the bat my first question regarding this definition is whether the second clause is to be interpreted as also restricting $\mathcal{B} \supset \mathcal{A}$ to only those which are subsets of $I$. As such seems the most reasonable and otherwise it would all get super messy, I think I can safely assume that is implicit in the definition?

Additionally, is the "proper" character of the filter stated in the third clause essential to it? That is, is it yet another thing all filters (at least those we are examining here) will verify or is it yet another demarcation (such as "ultrafilter," "free filter," "principal ultrafilter," etc.)?

Additionally, Dalen provides the following example, which confuses me also on similar grounds:

*Example 4.5.2* The following sets are filters:

1. $\mathcal{F} = \{A | A \supseteq A_0\}$, for $A_0 \neq \emptyset$ [should I assume $\mathcal{F}$ to actually be $\{A \neq \emptyset | A \supseteq A_0\}$?)

I thank in advance any help and/or comments clarifying the matter here exposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is correct as stated: once a nonempty $A_0$ is picked, the set of supersets of that $A_0$ is a filter. The point is that each nonempty $A_0$ determines a filter on $I$. For example, if $I=\{1,2,3\}$ and $A_0=\{2\}$, we get the filter $$\{\{2\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}.$$ Crucially, note that a nonempty set is never a subset of an/the empty set!

Re: your first question, the "$\mathcal{F}\subset\mathcal{P}(I)$" bit at the start of the definition gives you the further restriction you (correctly) guess at in your first question.

Finally, in my experience filters are **always** proper subsets of $\mathcal{P}(I)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! For some reason it seems I was repeatedly and systematically reading the superset symbol as a subset one/not reasoning it out and that was the source of my confusion regarding the example provided. Thanks for all!